# graphql refetchQueries is not working in react-native

Tags: react-native, graphql

I am using react-native with apollo-client. Others queries are working fine with refetch but this refetch results in:
`

```js
 WARN  Unknown query {
  "kind": "Document",
  "definitions": [
    {
      "kind": "OperationDefinition",
      "operation": "query",
      "variableDefinitions": [
        {
          "kind": "VariableDefinition",
          "variable": {
            "kind": "Variable",
            "name": {
              "kind": "Name",
              "value": "where"
            }
          },
          "type": {
            "kind": "NonNullType",
            "type": {
              "kind": "NamedType",
              "name": {
                "kind": "Name",
                "value": "AppointmentWhereInput"
              }
            }
          },
          "directives": []
        }
      ],
      "directives": [],
      "selectionSet": {
        "kind": "SelectionSet",
        "selections": [
          {
            "kind": "Field",
            "name": {
              "kind": "Name",
              "value": "appointments"
            },
            "arguments": [
              {
                "kind": "Argument",
                "name": {
                  "kind": "Name",
                  "value": "where"
                },
                "value": {
                  "kind": "Variable",
                  "name": {
                    "kind": "Name",
                    "value": "where"
                  }
                }
              }
            ],
            "directives": [],
            "selectionSet": {
              "kind": "SelectionSet",
              "selections": [
                {
                  "kind": "Field",
                  "name": {
                    "kind": "Name",
                    "value": "id"
                  },
                  "arguments": [],
                  "directives": []
                },
                {
                  "kind": "Field",
                  "name": {
                    "kind": "Name",
                    "value": "date"
                  },
                  "arguments": [],
                  "directives": []
                },
                {
                  "kind": "Field",
                  "name": {
                    "kind": "Name",
                    "value": "slot"
                  },
                  "arguments": [],
                  "directives": []
                },
                {
                  "kind": "Field",
                  "name": {
                    "kind": "Name",
                    "value": "paymentMode"
                  },
                  "arguments": [],
                  "directives": []
                },
                {
                  "kind": "Field",
                  "name": {
                    "kind": "Name",
                    "value": "status"
                  },
                  "arguments": [],
                  "directives": []
                },
                {
                  "kind": "Field",
                  "name": {
                    "kind": "Name",
                    "value": "allergy"
                  },
                  "arguments": [],
                  "directives": []
                },
                {
                  "kind": "Field",
                  "name": {
                    "kind": "Name",
                    "value": "appointmentType"
                  },
                  "arguments": [],
                  "directives": []
                },
                {
                  "kind": "Field",
                  "name": {
                    "kind": "Name",
                    "value": "clinic"
                  },
                  "arguments": [],
                  "directives": []
                },
                {
                  "kind": "Field",
                  "name": {
                    "kind": "Name",
                    "value": "report"
                  },
                  "arguments": [],
                  "directives": []
                },
                {
                  "kind": "Field",
                  "name": {
                    "kind": "Name",
                    "value": "amount"
                  },
                  "arguments": [],
                  "directives": []
                },
                {
                  "kind": "Field",
                  "name": {
                    "kind": "Name",
                    "value": "patientStatus"
                  },
                  "arguments": [],
                  "directives": []
                },
                {
                  "kind": "Field",
                  "name": {
                    "kind": "Name",
                    "value": "pregnancyMonth"
                  },
                  "arguments": [],
                  "directives": []
                },
                {
                  "kind": "Field",
                  "name": {
                    "kind": "Name",
                    "value": "appointmentNumber"
                  },
                  "arguments": [],
                  "directives": []
                },
                {
                  "kind": "Field",
                  "name": {
                    "kind": "Name",
                    "value": "registrationNumber"
                  },
                  "arguments": [],
                  "directives": [],
                  "selectionSet": {
                    "kind": "SelectionSet",
                    "selections": [
                      {
                        "kind": "Field",
                        "name": {
                          "kind": "Name",
                          "value": "RegistrationNumber"
                        },
                        "arguments": [],
                        "directives": []
                      },
                      {
                        "kind": "Field",
                        "name": {
                          "kind": "Name",
                          "value": "name"
                        },
                        "arguments": [],
                        "directives": []
                      },
                      {
                        "kind": "Field",
                        "name": {
                          "kind": "Name",
                          "value": "mobile"
                        },
                        "arguments": [],
                        "directives": []
                      },
                      {
                        "kind": "Field",
                        "name": {
                          "kind": "Name",
                          "value": "age"
                        },
                        "arguments": [],
                        "directives": []
                      },
                      {
                        "kind": "Field",
                        "name": {
                          "kind": "Name",
                          "value": "gender"
                        },
                        "arguments": [],
                        "directives": []
                      },
                      {
                        "kind": "Field",
                        "name": {
                          "kind": "Name",
                          "value": "appointemntCount"
                        },
                        "arguments": [
                          {
                            "kind": "Argument",
                            "name": {
                              "kind": "Name",
                              "value": "where"
                            },
                            "value": {
                              "kind": "ObjectValue",
                              "fields": [
                                {
                                  "kind": "ObjectField",
                                  "name": {
                                    "kind": "Name",
                                    "value": "status"
                                  },
                                  "value": {
                                    "kind": "ObjectValue",
                                    "fields": [
                                      {
                                        "kind": "ObjectField",
                                        "name": {
                                          "kind": "Name",
                                          "value": "equals"
                                        },
                                        "value": {
                                          "kind": "StringValue",
                                          "value": "confirmed",
                                          "block": false
                                        }
                                      }
                                    ]
                                  }
                                }
                              ]
                            }
                          }
                        ],
                        "directives": []
                      },
                      {
                        "kind": "Field",
                        "name": {
                          "kind": "Name",
                          "value": "appointemnt"
                        },
                        "arguments": [
                          {
                            "kind": "Argument",
                            "name": {
                              "kind": "Name",
                              "value": "where"
                            },
                            "value": {
                              "kind": "ObjectValue",
                              "fields": [
                                {
                                  "kind": "ObjectField",
                                  "name": {
                                    "kind": "Name",
                                    "value": "status"
                                  },
                                  "value": {
                                    "kind": "ObjectValue",
                                    "fields": [
                                      {
                                        "kind": "ObjectField",
                                        "name": {
                                          "kind": "Name",
                                          "value": "equals"
                                        },
                                        "value": {
                                          "kind": "StringValue",
                                          "value": "confirmed",
                                          "block": false
                                        }
                                      }
                                    ]
                                  }
                                }
                              ]
                            }
                          }
                        ],
                        "directives": [],
                        "selectionSet": {
                          "kind": "SelectionSet",
                          "selections": [
                            {
                              "kind": "Field",
                              "name": {
                                "kind": "Name",
                                "value": "date"
                              },
                              "arguments": [],
                              "directives": []
                            },
                            {
                              "kind": "Field",
                              "name": {
                                "kind": "Name",
                                "value": "id"
                              },
                              "arguments": [],
                              "directives": []
                            },
                            {
                              "kind": "Field",
                              "name": {
                                "kind": "Name",
                                "value": "status"
                              },
                              "arguments": [],
                              "directives": []
                            },
                            {
                              "kind": "Field",
                              "name": {
                                "kind": "Name",
                                "value": "prescription"
                              },
                              "arguments": [],
                              "directives": [],
                              "selectionSet": {
                                "kind": "SelectionSet",
                                "selections": [
                                  {
                                    "kind": "Field",
                                    "name": {
                                      "kind": "Name",
                                      "value": "prescription"
                                    },
                                    "arguments": [],
                                    "directives": [],
                                    "selectionSet": {
                                      "kind": "SelectionSet",
                                      "selections": [
                                        {
                                          "kind": "Field",
                                          "name": {
                                            "kind": "Name",
                                            "value": "url"
                                          },
                                          "arguments": [],
                                          "directives": []
                                        },
                                        {
                                          "kind": "Field",
                                          "name": {
                                            "kind": "Name",
                                            "value": "__typename"
                                          }
                                        }
                                      ]
                                    }
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "kind": "Field",
                                    "name": {
                                      "kind": "Name",
                                      "value": "__typename"
                                    }
                                  }
                                ]
                              }
                            },
                            {
                              "kind": "Field",
                              "name": {
                                "kind": "Name",
                                "value": "bloodReport"
                              },
                              "arguments": [],
                              "directives": [],
                              "selectionSet": {
                                "kind": "SelectionSet",
                                "selections": [
                                  {
                                    "kind": "Field",
                                    "name": {
                                      "kind": "Name",
                                      "value": "bloodReport"
                                    },
                                    "arguments": [],
                                    "directives": [],
                                    "selectionSet": {
                                      "kind": "SelectionSet",
                                      "selections": [
                                        {
                                          "kind": "Field",
                                          "name": {
                                            "kind": "Name",
                                            "value": "url"
                                          },
                                          "arguments": [],
                                          "directives": []
                                        },
                                        {
                                          "kind": "Field",
                                          "name": {
                                            "kind": "Name",
                                            "value": "__typename"
                                          }
                                        }
                                      ]
                                    }
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "kind": "Field",
                                    "name": {
                                      "kind": "Name",
                                      "value": "__typename"
                                    }
                                  }
                                ]
                              }
                            },
                            {
                              "kind": "Field",
                              "name": {
                                "kind": "Name",
                                "value": "ultraSoundReport"
                              },
                              "arguments": [],
                              "directives": [],
                              "selectionSet": {
                                "kind": "SelectionSet",
                                "selections": [
                                  {
                                    "kind": "Field",
                                    "name": {
                                      "kind": "Name",
                                      "value": "ultraSoundReport"
                                    },
                                    "arguments": [],
                                    "directives": [],
                                    "selectionSet": {
                                      "kind": "SelectionSet",
                                      "selections": [
                                        {
                                          "kind": "Field",
                                          "name": {
                                            "kind": "Name",
                                            "value": "url"
                                          },
                                          "arguments": [],
                                          "directives": []
                                        },
                                        {
                                          "kind": "Field",
                                          "name": {
                                            "kind": "Name",
                                            "value": "__typename"
                                          }
                                        }
                                      ]
                                    }
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "kind": "Field",
                                    "name": {
                                      "kind": "Name",
                                      "value": "__typename"
                                    }
                                  }
                                ]
                              }
                            },
                            {
                              "kind": "Field",
                              "name": {
                                "kind": "Name",
                                "value": "__typename"
                              }
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "kind": "Field",
                        "name": {
                          "kind": "Name",
                          "value": "__typename"
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                },
                {
                  "kind": "Field",
                  "name": {
                    "kind": "Name",
                    "value": "pathology"
                  },
                  "arguments": [],
                  "directives": [],
                  "selectionSet": {
                    "kind": "SelectionSet",
                    "selections": [
                      {
                        "kind": "Field",
                        "name": {
                          "kind": "Name",
                          "value": "id"
                        },
                        "arguments": [],
                        "directives": []
                      },
                      {
                        "kind": "Field",
                        "name": {
                          "kind": "Name",
                          "value": "__typename"
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                },
                {
                  "kind": "Field",
                  "name": {
                    "kind": "Name",
                    "value": "diagnosticsCenter"
                  },
                  "arguments": [],
                  "directives": [],
                  "selectionSet": {
                    "kind": "SelectionSet",
                    "selections": [
                      {
                        "kind": "Field",
                        "name": {
                          "kind": "Name",
                          "value": "id"
                        },
                        "arguments": [],
                        "directives": []
                      },
                      {
                        "kind": "Field",
                        "name": {
                          "kind": "Name",
                          "value": "__typename"
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                },
                {
                  "kind": "Field",
                  "name": {
                    "kind": "Name",
                    "value": "createdAt"
                  },
                  "arguments": [],
                  "directives": []
                },
                {
                  "kind": "Field",
                  "name": {
                    "kind": "Name",
                    "value": "__typename"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "loc": {
    "start": 0,
    "end": 924
  }
} requested in refetchQueries options.include array
```

Comment: Please show your query and how you're using refetch. Just posting an error message isn't (usually) enough for people to help you.